# Delphi 2006 refactoring keyboard mappings

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

How do I change the default refactoring keyboard mappings in Delphi 2006?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably know, in D2006 you can find the settings under:
  Tools > Options > Editor Options > Key Mappings
Also, there is the "Editor speedsetting" under:
  Tools > Options > Editor Options

However, these don't give you direct control over the keymappings, they just let you choose a keymapping from among the installed Enhancement Modules.  Per D2006 Help:

> Enhancement modules
>
> Enhancement modules are special packages that are installed and
>   registered and use the keyboard
>   binding features that can be developed
>   using the Open Tools API. You can
>   create enhancement modules that
>   contain new keystrokes or apply new
>   operations to existing keystrokes.
>
> Once installed, the enhancement modules are displayed in the
>   Enhancement modules list box. Clicking
>   the check box next to the enhancement
>   module enables it and unchecking it
>   disables it. Key mapping defined in an
>   installed and enabled enhancement
>   module overrides any existing key
>   mapping defined for that key in the
>   key mapping module which is currently
>   in effect.

Clearly, this is not a quick do-it-yourself setting.

**[GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org)** has a feature supporting [IDE Menu Shortcuts](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/ide_menu_shortcuts.html) that support hotkey configuration of any IDE menu command, including refactoring commands.

Comment: Thanks Argalatyr, your answer confirms my own experience (no simple integrated way to override a key mapping). I already use CnPack IDE enhancements so I'm a bit worried that installing GExperts would mess up some things. But if I cannot find a more specific solution in the near future I will give it a try.

Comment: I use both GExperts and CnPack IDE Enhancements in D2007; they work fine together. You'll end up disabling little bits of them over time to stop duplicate functionality, but there were no other problems.